# Появление и исчезновение объекта работает только в одну сторону!

Tags: c#, unity3d

столкнулся с такой проблемой
При нажатии кнопки А, объект сначала появляется, а потом исчезает с задержкой 2 секунды, НО повторить операцию уже не получается.
(Изначально объект включен (setactive(true))
А если он выключен, то и вовсе ничего не работает.
Хотелось бы узнать в чем ошибка и способы ее исправления

```
private bool isAttack = false;
 


    public void Start()
    {

       
       
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
      
       
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && isAttack == false)
        {
            isAttack = true;            
             gameObject.SetActive(true);
             
            
            Invoke("ResetAttack", 2f);
        }
    }
    void ResetAttack()
    {
        isAttack = false;
       gameObject.SetActive(false);

    }
```

Comment: Как бы это ни было странно, но не активный объект не активен! В нём не происходят методы unity. Исправить просто, инпутами и исполнением занимается не один и тот же объект/класс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Врагом я называю Ваш "объект".
Я так понимаю, что Ваш скрипт висит на враге, так что...
...Попробуйте поставить Ваш скрипт не на врага, а, например, на камеру или пустой объект. Если этот скрипт "висит" на враге, то, когда враг не активен (выключен (SetActive(false)), скрипт просто не работает, потому что когда выключен объект, то и все скрипты (и компоненты) на нём перестают работать.